# Какие вопросы могут задавать на собеседовании верстальщику?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Какие вопросы могут задавать на собеседовании при устройстве на работу верстальщиком?

Comment: css и html знаешь?)

Comment: Естесственно

Comment: а action scripts, jscripts, flash, html5, photoshop?

Comment: Photoshop, CSS3, поверхностно HTML5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотря к кому попадешь на собеседование, если к техническому специалисту, то вопросы могут быть какими угодно, если вы справитесь с основами, то могут пойти каверзные вопросы из собственного опыта разработчика, главное не волноваться и не пугаться того чего не знаете.

Если собеседование будет проводить пм, то берите инициативу в свои руки, если видите, что он толком не знает, что спрашивать, сами расскажите о самом сложном проекте который у вас был, что вы сделали и как решали свои сложные задачи, с чем интересным сталкивались, какие технологии или примочки применяли.

Также нужно показать, что яваскрипт для вас это первостепенная задача для обучения и совершенствования, надо показать, что вам можно доверить любую клиентскую часть, а если вы столкнетесь с трудностями, то вы их быстро решите, потому что знаете, где и что именно искать.

И конечно желаю удачи на собеседовании...

Answer (score 1):

Могут задать пару каверзных вопросов по взаимодействию блоков: разберитесь с relative, fixed, absolute... и их комбинациях.

Могут предложить сделать кроссбраузерные закругленные уголки с минимальным числом элементов.

Могут спросить чем em отличается от i, а strong от b.

Короче, если шарите хорошо - справитесь. Если не очень - не стесняйтесь ответить, что чего-то не знаете, но не забывайте уточнить, что всегда сможете быстро посмотреть в документации. Потом - да, тестовое задание. От скорости, качества и кроссбраузерности напрямую зависит вероятность попадения в команду, если вы - мужчина.

Comment: @knes т.е. если вы женщина, то в команду попасть вообще не вариант? или от скорости и качества не зависит? )

Comment: Скорее всего хотелось сказать, что наоборот милым девушкам проще попасть в команду, если директор мужчина. Ну я так не думаю

Comment: @FLK, нет. Не секрет, что женщинам вообще устроиться на работу сложнее. Так что если вы женщина, зависимость вероятности не прямая: появляется куча других переменных =(

Милым девушкам проще попасть в команду, но вряд ли на ответственную работу. Соответственно, страдает зарплата. И таких мест большинство: в редкой компании отдел кадров смотрит исключительно на знания.

Comment: @knes, а разве принимает на работу отдел кадров ? IMHO они просто оформляют.

Comment: Они оформляют. Но они составляют списки для просмотра руководителем. Т.е. если они отсеят, то этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Надо же. 30 лет работаю и ни один мой знакомый с такими порядками не сталкивался. Всегда сначала договариваешься с боссом, а он дает команду оформлять.

Comment: @avp, стоп. Где работают те вредные тетки/дядьки, которые ни фига не знают, но задают типовые вопросы и лазают по сайтам с вакансиями? Разве не в отделе кадров?

Comment: Наверное где как. Я их обычно видел в том же отделе, который возглавляет босс, дающий потом команду отделу кадров. 

@knes, все это зависит от количества бюрократов в конторе. Если их много, лучше другое место поискать.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы задавал вопросы по:
1) Прошлой работе, к-во и качество проектов, портфолио.

2) Общим темам, теория. Чем див от спана отличается? Вложенность тегов.
Нужно ли в 5-м ХТМЛ закрывать /> одиночные теги. Отличие i от em и т.д.

3) Пару заданий "на внимательность" - найти ошибку в тегах атрибутах. Изменить шаблон чтобы было меньше элементов в менюшке (позаботясь об индексации и спрайтах), Как сделать то-то и то-то в CSS (закругленные уголки - тут и кроссбраузерность и напишет ли 2 радиуса по x и y). Как убрать маркер у ul.

4) Практические знания, если хоть несколько сайтов сайтов сверстал - ответит. На стиль дам задание где текст в виде фото (что исправишь?), в резиновом дизайне выброшу минимальную ширину (тот же вопрос).

5) Приоритеты, несколько правил к одному элементу. Какой стиль "победит" - атрибут в теге, или !important, в теге style класс или наследование тегов,
по ИД и классам вопросы.

6) Позиционирование, зет-индекс. Наследование свойств. 
"тег+тег" vs "тег>тег" vs "тег тег".

7) Задачки на кроссбраузерность. Что нужно сделать, чтобы в браузере таком-то отображалось адекватно. Настройки пользователя. Сброс. Универсальный селектор.

6+7)Можно на *{font-size: 200%;} и вложенные элементы дать. Каким будет размер шрифта.

8) Типы верстки. Табличная, адаптивная.
Вопросы по стилю. Как больше нравится, почему? Как именует и группирует в CSS. Как часто оставляет комментарии и что вообще комментирует. Что геморно делать. На чем верстает. Что нравится делать, что нет.